# Fade in fade out in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout, fadein, fadeout

I continue the work on: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7315/fade-in-and-fade-out-in-pure-javascript

What is the best way to detect if the fade in or fade out is completed before setting a new function. This is my way, but I guess there is a much better way?

I added the alert's to make it easier for you to see.

Why I want to do this is because: If one press the buttons before the for loop has finnished, the animation will look bad.

I want the buttons to work only when the fadeing is completed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
        <div>
        <span id="fade_in">Fade In</span> | 
        <span id="fade_out">Fade Out</span></div>
        <div id="fading_div" style="display:none;height:100px;background:#f00">Fading Box</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var done_or_not = 'done';

// fade in function
function function_opacity(opacity_value, fade_in_or_fade_out) { // fade_in_or_out - 0 = fade in, 1 = fade out
    document.getElementById('fading_div').style.opacity = opacity_value / 100;
    document.getElementById('fading_div').style.filter = 'alpha(opacity='+opacity_value+')';
    if(fade_in_or_fade_out == 1 && opacity_value == 1)
    {
        document.getElementById('fading_div').style.display = 'none';
        done_or_not = 'done';
        alert(done_or_not);
    }
    if(fade_in_or_fade_out == 0 && opacity_value == 100)
    {
        done_or_not = 'done';
        alert(done_or_not);
    }

}





window.onload =function(){

// fade in click
document.getElementById('fade_in').onclick = function fadeIn() {
    document.getElementById('fading_div').style.display='block';
    var timer = 0;
    if (done_or_not == 'done')
    {
        for (var i=1; i<=100; i++) {
            set_timeout_in = setTimeout("function_opacity("+i+",0)", timer * 10);
            timer++;
            done_or_not = 'not_done'
        }
    }
};

// fade out click
document.getElementById('fade_out').onclick = function fadeOut() {
    clearTimeout(set_timeout_in);
    var timer = 0;
    if (done_or_not == 'done')
    {
        for (var i=100; i>=1; i--) {
            set_timeout_out = setTimeout("function_opacity("+i+",1)", timer * 10);
            timer++;
            done_or_not = 'not_done'
        }
    }
};



}// END window.onload
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery? It makes chaining events very easy.

Comment: Why are you writing these by yourself, when a lot of mature javascript  animation libraries are out there. For example jQuery has some built in effect. script.aculo.us is another popular JS animation lib.

Comment: jQuery also implements fadein/out in old versions of IE.  Your opacity manipulation will not play.

Comment: Or if you want to learn the best way to do it may be you can study the source of these libraries. Most of them are open source.

Comment: Sorry about this "why" comment, but I question whether you really want to make the visitor wait until the animation completes, which might take seconds. When I press the button, I always want the action to take place right now. If your code needs fade to be all done at that time, then you can just force it to be complete. If you've already considered and discarded this idea, I apologize for the detour.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I just prefer learning the language of javascript :) I just need the fade function on my page, nothing else.

Comment: If you like pain, you could use CSS transitions and fire your code on [the transition end event](http://dropshado.ws/post/1393565298/css-transition-end-events). Right now, this sucks. In the future it will be "the right way".

Comment: Is it bad performance "setting" and "testing" varibales?

Comment: Props for vanilla. This article might be useful: [How to implement the fadeIn() and fadeOut() animation methods in pure JavaScript](http://blog.gabrieleromanato.com/javascript-implementing-the-fadein-and-fadeout-methods-without-jquery/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with some of the comments. There are many nice JavaScript libraries that not only make it easier to write code but also take some of the browser compatibility issues out of your hands.

Having said that, you could modify your fade functions to accept a callback:

```
function fadeIn(callback) {
    return function() {
        function step() {
            // Perform one step of the animation

            if (/* test whether animation is done*/) {
                callback();   // <-- call the callback
            } else {
                setTimeout(step, 10);
            }
        }
        setTimeout(step, 0); // <-- begin the animation
    };
}

document.getElementById('fade_in').onclick = fadeIn(function() {
    alert("Done.");
});
```

This way, `fadeIn` will return a function. That function will be used as the `onclick` handler. You can pass `fadeIn` a function, which will be called after you've performed the last step of your animation. The inner function (the one returned by `fadeIn`) will still have access to `callback`, because JavaScript creates a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) around it.

Your animation code could still use a lot of improvement, but this is in a nutshell what most JavaScript libraries do:

- Perform the animation in steps;
- Test to see if you're done;
- Call the user's callback after the last step.

One last thing to keep in mind: animation can get pretty complex. If, for instance, you want a reliable way to determine the duration of the animation, you'll want to use tween functions (also something most libraries do). If mathematics isn't your strong point, this might not be so pleasant...

---

In response to your comment: you say you want it to keep working the same way; *"If the function is bussy, nothing shall happen."*

So, if I understand correctly, you want the animations to be blocking. In fact, I can tell you two things:

1. Your animations aren't blocking (at least, not the animations themselves -- read below).
2. You can still make it work the way you want with any kind of asynchronous animations.

This is what you are using `done_or_not` for. This is, in fact, a common pattern. Usually a boolean is used (`true` or `false`) instead of a string, but the principle is always the same:

```
// Before anything else:
var done = false;

// Define a callback:
function myCallback() {
    done = true;
    // Do something else
}

// Perform the asynchronous action (e.g. animations):
done = false;
doSomething(myCallback);
```

I've created a simple example of the kind of animation you want to perform, only using jQuery. You can have a look at it here: http://jsfiddle.net/PPvG/k73hU/

```
var buttonFadeIn = $('#fade_in');
var buttonFadeOut = $('#fade_out');
var fadingDiv = $('#fading_div');

var done = true;

buttonFadeIn.click(function() {
    if (done) {
        // Set done to false:
        done = false;

        // Start the animation:
        fadingDiv.fadeIn(
            1500, // <- 1500 ms = 1.5 second
            function() {
                // When the animation is finished, set done to true again:
                done = true;
            }
        );
    }
});

buttonFadeOut.click(function() {
    // Same as above, but using 'fadeOut'.
});
```

Because of the `done` variable, the buttons will only respond if the animation is done. And as you can see, the code is really short and readable. That's the benefit of using a library like jQuery. But of course you're free to build your own solution.

Regarding performance: most JS libraries use tweens to perform animations, which is usually more performant than fixed steps. It definitely looks smoother to the user, because the position depends on the **time** that has passed, instead of on the **number of steps** that have passed.

I hope this helps. :-)

Comment: Thanks PPcG, thansk for your answer. I want the function to work in the same way as it does today. If the function is bussy, nothing shall happen, no function i the queu. Maybe my method of "setting" and "checking" variables isn't that bad? Or would you say it't slow down the performance?

Comment: Thanks PPcG, I continue on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7315/fade-in-and-fade-out-in-pure-javascript

Answer (score 1):

you could move your fade code to its own function

```
var alpha = 100
function fade() { 
    if (alpha > 0) {
        alpha -= 1;    
        *your opacity changes*
        (e.g.: .opacity = (alpha/100);
        .style.filter = 'alpha(opacity='+alpha+')';)
    }
    else {
        *complete - modify the click event*
    }
 }
```

you may want to add .MozOpacity to go with .opacity and .filter.  as mentioned in the comments above, though, cancelling or forcing a completed fade may be better than preventing new clicks while the loop's running.

ps: i respect you for coding that yourself.  javascript libraries are overused and often unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks stackuser10210. I agree with out about libraries. I want to learn javascript before using them.

Comment: it's nice to know exactly what your code is doing and to keep things as lightweight as possible, i think.  _"We know you like programming, so we put a language in your language so you can code while you code."_ - Fictional jLib : )

Answer (score 0):

It could be resolved in few ways. Please take a look at code at the stub of my home page
`http://marek.zielonkowski.com/thescript.js`
I did it by clearing the time out (I think, I don't remember well because it was few years ago) 
`clearInterval(isMoving);`
or

```
this.fadeIn = function (){
    iCurrentAlpha = (iCurrentAlpha===null) ? alpha : iCurrentAlpha;
    clearInterval(isFading);
    isFading = setInterval(function(){changeFading(1);},timer);
}
```

Or You can code your custom events and dispatch something like 'onFadeOutStop' to the listener.

And please do not use setTimeout('function_name()') with quotes - because it is bad habbit (set Timeout behaves then like eval which supposed to be evil :)

Comment: Thanks, will have a look :) How can I do it without the quotes in this case?

Comment: like here `isFading = setInterval(function(){changeFading(1);},timer);`

Answer (score 0):

You should use jquery. you can run a function after an animation

```
$('#clickthis').click(function(){
     //jquery has really easy way of animating css properties
     //the 5000 is the duration in milliseconds
     $('#animatethis').animate({opacity:0},5000,function(){

         //this will only run once the animation is complete
         alert('finished animating');

     });

     //or use the function..
     $('#animatethis').fadeOut(5000,function(){
          //this will only run once the animation is complete
         alert('finished fading out'); 
     });
});
```

that should do it. I didn't test it so forgive me if it has any errors.

-L